# What does the Grimoire of Sacrifice talent actually do?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just respecced my warlock to Affliction and picked up Grimoire of Sacrifice as one of my talents.

The description says:

> You sacrifice your demon to gain one of its abilities, increase the power of many of your single target spells by 50% and regenerate 2% of maximum health every 5 sec.

and I can't seem to figure out the demon ability part. I assume it varies per demon, but which ability do you inherit from which demon? Should I just drag one of the demons' abilities to my action bars?

How do I make this thing go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra ability is controlled by the [Command Demon](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=119898) spell. Normally, if you don't have a demon summoned, Command Demon is disabled. When you have a demon summoned, Command Demon becomes activatable and is replaced with a specific ability that relates to that demon:

- Felguard: Felstorm
- Felhunter: Spell Lock
- Imp: Cauterize Master
- Succubus: Whiplash
- Voidwalker: Disarm

When you activate [Grimoire of Sacrifice](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=108503), your demon goes away, but instead of Command Demon going back to being disabled, it gets replaced with a different ability, depending on which demon you sacrificed:

- Felguard: [Pursuit](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=30151)
- Felhunter: [Spell Lock](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=19647)
- Imp: [Singe Magic](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=89808/singe-magic)
- Succubus: [Seduction](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=6358)
- Voidwalker: [Shadow Bulwark](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=17767)